# serial port for MindWave in Windows8.1

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, usb, mindwave

How can I find what is the serial port assigned to the MindWave USB in Windows8.1? The code I am using has this for Mac OSX:

```
import platform
import sys, time
from mindwave import bluetooth_headset
import httplib, urllib, urllib2
import json

#serial_port = '/dev/tty.MindWaveMobile-DevA-10'
```

Here's what my device manager shows:
[image]

I'd like to know how to change line 10 of http://pastebin.com/jR21F4Xf in order to make it work in Windows. Currently MindWave USB Dongle is connected to COM4.

Here's the config file:

```
{
    "mindwave_serial_port": "COM4",
    "hue_bridge_addr": "10.0.0.225",
    "user": "mona6_000",
    "send_to_gatd": "True",
    "show_spectrum": "True"
}
```

Here's what `MindWave Manager` shows:
[image]

Here's what I get in PowerShell:
[image]

I have installed `pyserial` using `easy_install`:
[image]

However I cannot import it in python interactive shell while I don't get any error running my code:
[image]

Comment: Should just be `COM4`, e.g. `connection = serial.Serial(port = 'COM4', ...`.

Comment: so the code is like http://pastebin.com/jR21F4Xf and I don't know how to change the code to work with the rest of python code. Can you please take a look at it and tell me how to change the line 10?

Comment: It's getting the serial port from a config file somewhere. To override that, try adding the line `self.serial_port = 'COM4'` right after the first instance of `self.get_config()`.

Comment: hi 101, can you please take a look at the update?

Comment: That should work then, as it's already `COM4`. So don't change anything. However, it also depends what happens in the function `headset.Headset(self.serial_port)`, which presumably uses pyserial.

Comment: seems `pyserial` doesn't have a 64 bit version https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial

Comment: Generally people use 32-bit Python, even on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: So, I installed the pyserial using easy_install. still I have the same problem. Can you please take a look at the screenshots I have added now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97355/discussion-between-101-and-mona-jalal).